# focus content node of pagination control

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a ListView as a content node of the JavaFX pagination control.
My aim is to set the focus to the ListView after a new page is selected.
The problem with my approach is sometimes the ListView has the focus but sometimes not.

How can i ensure, that the ListView will have the focus, after a new page is selected?

Platform:
Windows 7
JDK 1.8.0.25 (64-Bit)

code:

```
package test.focus;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Pagination;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pagination pagination = new Pagination(5);
        final ObservableList<String> texts = FXCollections.observableArrayList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j");
        final ListView<String> textsListView = new ListView<>();
        pagination.setPageFactory(new Callback<Integer, Node>() {

            @Override
            public Node call(Integer page) {
                textsListView.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(texts.subList(page, page + 2)));
                textsListView.getSelectionModel().select(0);
                // Platform.runLater does not work, too
                textsListView.requestFocus();
                return textsListView;
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(pagination);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        stage.setTitle("Focus issue");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two things to have the focus always on the list:

- `pagination`should not be part of the focus traversal cycle.
- Every time the list loses the focus, it should request it again.

This works for me:

```
    final ListView<String> textsListView = new ListView<>();
    textsListView.focusedProperty().addListener((ov,b,b1)->{
        if(!b1){
            textsListView.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    pagination.setFocusTraversable(false);
    pagination.setPageFactory(page -> {
        textsListView.setItems(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(texts.subList(page, page + 2)));
        textsListView.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        textsListView.requestFocus();           
        return textsListView;
    });
```

**EDIT**

In order to avoid the list requests for the focus every time it loses it, this approach will request the focus for the list only when the new page is loaded:

```
    final ListView<String> textsListView = new ListView<>();
    final BooleanProperty loaded=new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);         

    pagination.setFocusTraversable(false);
    pagination.setPageFactory(page -> {
        textsListView.setItems(
             FXCollections.observableArrayList(texts.subList(page, page + 2)));
        textsListView.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        loaded.set(true);
        return textsListView;
    });

    loaded.addListener((ov,b,b1)->{
        if(b1){
            textsListView.requestFocus();
            loaded.set(false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: it works in this use case, but i can't request the focus all the time it's lost, cause in a real application there are other controls, which must be able to get the focus.

Comment: @coder I've edited my answer with a new approach, that avoids requesting the focus every time. It works for the simple case you have proposed. BUT I'm afraid it won't work if the root or the scene have more focusable nodes. Somehow the focus goes sometimes to the first of them (the top node), sometimes goes to the list. In this general case, one ugly (and surely not acceptable) solution is set for all the nodes `setFocusTraversable(false)`.

Comment: @coder I've just found there's an unresolved issue on JIRA [RT-38543](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38543) refering to this problem.